# Removing backslashed substring from string

Tags: python

I have a list of substrings that needs to be removed from a string.

I have a blacklist of substrings that needs to be removed from the string when they occur in certain patterns.

Here's my code:

```
blacklist = ['bad','bye','hello']
mystring = "a\hello\hi\this_bye\end\my_bad.c"

for i in blacklist:
    mystring = mystring.replace("\\"+i,"").replace("_"+i,"")
```

But now this code returns mystring's value as

```
"a\\hello\\hi\\this_bye\\end\x08ad"
```

instead of

```
"a\hi\this\end\my.c"
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It returns the correct one for me, what encoding are you using? Do `import sys; sys.getdefaultencoding()` for getting the system default encoding

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me. I am using Python 2.7.
As mentioned by Anand, please check which encoding you are using.

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```